# Short header for a very long Section's title in beamer presentation R Markdown (Pandoc)

Tags: header, yaml, r-markdown, beamer

I am working on a `beamer_presentation` which consists of several sections. The section titles are too long to fit into the CambridgeUS headline. I have already tried several options from related latex sources to use some short title for the section (say just "Chapter 1" instead of "Chapter 1 with a very-very-very-very-very long title" by `\AtBeginSection{\title[Short title]{Long title}}`) but yet can't figure out how to manage this in header-includes of R Markdown YAML. I set the section title through `#` in Markdown

````
---
title: Title for the whole presentation
subtitle: 'Presentation'
author: 
- Author

institute: "Institution"
date: " `r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: true
    highlight: tango
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    colortheme: "lily"
    fonttheme: "serif"
    slide_level: 3
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title[Presentation]{Title for whole presentation}}
  - \renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}
  - \def\sectionname{Chapter}
  - \AtBeginSubsection{}

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```


# Chapter 1 with a very-very-very-very-very long title
## Intro

### The first page
````

Comment: `\AtBeginSection{\title[Short title]{Long title}})` does not work because `\title` sets the title of the presentation, not of the section. In a real beamer document, your problem would be easy to solve with `\section[short version for headline]{Chapter 1 with a very-very-very-very-very long title}`

Comment: I see. Thank you, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! Actually, the last option I was thinking about was to get Pandoc given .tex file and to start exploring latex :)

Comment: exploring latex is always a good idea, no matter the circumstances :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz noted with thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In beamer, this is trivial, you can use `\section[short version]{long version}`. But Markdown makes such an easy job excruciatingly difficult.

However you can trick markdown like this:

````
---
title: Title for the whole presentation
subtitle: 'Presentation'
author: 
- Author

institute: "Institution"
date: " `r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    highlight: tango
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    colortheme: "lily"
    fonttheme: "serif"
    slide_level: 3
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title[Presentation]{Title for whole presentation}}
  - \renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}
  - \def\sectionname{Chapter}
  - \AtBeginSubsection{}

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

```{=latex}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
\section[short version for headline]{Chapter 1 with a very-very-very-very-very long title}
\subsection[short subsection for headline]{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The first page}
```

some text
````

(be careful where you place this command, otherwise you might end up with empty extra frames - that's why I had to switch off the automatic toc and insert it manually...)

[image]

Comment: Wow! @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I really appreciate your help! I did think that there must be a way to trick R Markdown here but I did not find this way myself. The cod works perfectly!